# Bootstrapper Setup Failed - 0x80070645

Tags: wix

I am having difficulty getting a chained .msi install to work using Burn to create my setup. It appears to install correctly and then at the end, a Setup Failed dialog with 0x80070645 - This action is only valid for products that are currently installed. The .msi payload looks like it installed correctly and indeed, I see it in ARP. I am using an Instance Transform.

I searched the registry before the install and did not find {3332C54F-3BED-4A25-8699-331A10B0F24E}.

Any help, comments or suggestions would be enthusiastically, eagerly and appreciatively received...  I am new to this install game and I have so much to learn.

OS Win7 x64
WiX v3.6.2610.0 Release
Visual Studio 2008

This is the instance transform in the SetupProject1.msi:

```
    <Property Id="RADPRODUCTID" Value="UndefinedRADProductID" />

    <InstanceTransforms Property="RADPRODUCTID">
        <Instance Id="Instance1" ProductCode="5D52FCDA-9630-4FED-9D44-B9099AAFE624" ProductName="RADInstance1"/>
        <Instance Id="Instance2" ProductCode="086677C8-07A1-4D1F-B3F9-86C7CF8F3CE4" ProductName="RADInstance2"/>
        <Instance Id="Instance3" ProductCode="3332C54F-3BED-4A25-8699-331A10B0F24E" ProductName="RADInstance3"/>
    </InstanceTransforms>
```

This is the Bundle.wxs code:

        
        
        
            
            
                
                
                -->

This is the Bootstrapper log:

```
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:47]: Burn v3.6.2610.0, path: L:\bldtools\Setup\WiX\Bootstrapper3\Bootstrapper3\bin\Debug\Bootstrapper3.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{26DF0A77-1345-4393-853C-7BFEAE2DCEEA} {10F18146-372B-4202-AE80-5A4E25729CB9} 6844'
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:47]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\hrody\AppData\Local\Temp\Bootstrapper3_20120214094447.log'
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:47]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Bootstrapper3'
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:47]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'L:\bldtools\Setup\WiX\Bootstrapper3\Bootstrapper3\bin\Debug\Bootstrapper3.exe'
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:48]: Detect 1 packages
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:48]: Detected package: SetupProject1.msi, state: Absent, cached: No
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:48]: Detect complete, result: 0x0
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Plan 1 packages, action: Install
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_SetupProject1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\hrody\AppData\Local\Temp\Bootstrapper3_20120214094447_0_SetupProject1.msi.log'
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_SetupProject1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\hrody\AppData\Local\Temp\Bootstrapper3_20120214094447_0_SetupProject1.msi_rollback.log'
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Planned package: SetupProject1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Apply begin
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\hrody\AppData\Local\Temp\{c1edb98f-61a0-4e47-81cf-093309e0e72b}\.be\Bootstrapper3.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{c1edb98f-61a0-4e47-81cf-093309e0e72b}\Bootstrapper3.exe'
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:52]: Registering bundle dependency provider: {c1edb98f-61a0-4e47-81cf-093309e0e72b}, version: 1.0.0.0
        [1ABC:1E94][2012-02-14T09:44:53]: Verified acquired payload: SetupProject1.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SetupProject1.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}v1.0.0.1\SetupProject1.msi.
        [1ABC:1E94][2012-02-14T09:44:53]: Verified acquired payload: cabF52D1B2425057F8281C66111B2795130 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabF52D1B2425057F8281C66111B2795130, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}v1.0.0.1\cab1.cab.
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:53]: Applying package: SetupProject1.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}v1.0.0.1\SetupProject1.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" TRANSFORMS=":Instance3" MSINEWINSTANCE="1" INSTALLFOLDER="C:\temp\TestPID3" RADAPPLICATION="TestPID3"'
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Error 0x80070645: Failed to register source directory: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}v1.0.0.1; product: {7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Error 0x80070645: Failed to register source directory.
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Error 0x80070645: Failed to execute MSI package.
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Error 0x80070645: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Error 0x80070645: Failed to execute MSI package.
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Removing cached package: {7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}v1.0.0.1, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7CB17298-D56B-40C3-9040-D9CC676F4AFF}v1.0.0.1\
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Error 0x80070645: Failed to execute apply.
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Removing bundle dependency provider: {c1edb98f-61a0-4e47-81cf-093309e0e72b}
        [1ABC:212C][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Removing cached bundle: {c1edb98f-61a0-4e47-81cf-093309e0e72b}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{c1edb98f-61a0-4e47-81cf-093309e0e72b}\
        [1938:2568][2012-02-14T09:44:55]: Apply complete, result: 0x80070645 restart: No
```

The log from the .msi can be found here:

https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=77EA17723639BF45A66458C58EAEB9531E591E66%40US-MBX2.ingrnet.com&forum_name=wix-users

Marshall Rody
RAD Technical Consulting
Process, Power and Marine
Intergraph Corporation
300 Intergraph Way, Madison, AL 35758 USA
P 1.256.730.3298 F 1.256.730.3200
marshall.rody@intergraph.com, www.intergraph.comhttp://www.intergraph.com/

Comment: Per Rob Mensching via. WiX-Users
Burn (unfortunately) does not yet handle instance transforms. Switching
from the "non-transformed" MSI will confuse Burn currently. Something we
need to address but just won't get it in the first version.

Answer (score 0):

Per Rob Mensching via. WiX-Users
Burn (unfortunately) does not yet handle instance transforms. Switching
from the "non-transformed" MSI will confuse Burn currently. Something we
need to address but just won't get it in the first version.